# Robot Framework - query returned keyword types

Tags: python, types, robotframework, keyword

is there a means of querying the returned keyword variable types?
Trying to debug some scripts and would be really useful to have something like the Python `type(my_variable)` available?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using robot version 2.9 or above, you can use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword to use python's `type(myvariable)` by taking advantage of Evaluate's [variable substitution](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions):

For example:

```
*** Keywords ***
keyword that returns an int
    ${result}=  set variable  ${42}
    [return]    ${result}

keyword that returns a list
    ${result}=    create list   one  two  three
    [return]    ${result}

keyword that returns a string
    ${result}=    set variable  foo
    [return]    ${result}

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${result1}=    keyword that returns an int
    @{result2}=    keyword that returns a list
    ${result3}=    keyword that returns a string

    ${type1}=    evaluate    type($result1)
    ${type2}=    evaluate    type($result2)
    ${type3}=    evaluate    type($result3)

    should be equal as strings    ${type1}    <type 'int'>
    should be equal as strings    ${type2}    <type 'list'>
    should be equal as strings    ${type3}    <type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: Is the **Evaluate** keyword, which is verifying by comparison the only or main means of doing so? I can see the use, but it requires knowing the type for comparison. My keyword (built in a Python library) returns a string. But verification as 'unicode' failed... Which leaves me trying to work out which types I should be checking.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Yes, to verify the type of an object you need to "know the type for comparison". This is literally using python's `type` command to return then information which is exactly what you asked for in your question. You can, of course, write your own keyword in python that uses `type` or anything else, and convert the result into something usable by your tests.